# protractor can't detect angular component rendered page

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm using `e2e` test on my project, but there's some problems that make my tests fail.
this is my `app.po.ts`:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
    public baseUrl: string = browser.baseUrl;

    public navigateTo(url?: string) {
        browser.get(url || '/');
    }

    public getPageTitle() {
        return browser.getTitle();
    }

    public getCurrentUrl() {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl();
    }

    public getText(selector: string) {
        let elementText = element(by.css(selector)).getText();
        return elementText;
    }
}

export class LoginPage extends AppPage {
    setUser(text) {
        let selector = 'input[name=email]';
        let elementRef = element(by.css(selector));
        elementRef.sendKeys(text);
        return elementRef.getAttribute('value');
    }

    getUser() {
        element(by.css('input[name=email]')).getAttribute('value');
    }

    setPassword(text) {
        let selector = 'input[name=password]';
        let elementRef = element(by.css(selector));
        elementRef.sendKeys(text);
        return elementRef.getAttribute('value');
    }

    getPassword() {
        element(by.css('input[name=password]')).getAttribute('value');
    }

    submit() {
        let submitElm = element(by.css('#m_login_signin_submit'));
        submitElm.click();
    }
}
```

this is my test file:

```
import { AddNotificationGroup, AppPage, LoginPage } from './app.po';

describe('Admin Panel: Sample flow', () => {

    describe('Device List', () => {
        let page: AppPage;

        beforeEach(() => {
            page = new AppPage();
        });

        it('should display welcome message', async () => {
            page.navigateTo('/snmp-device-list');
            expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('DCMon Dashboard');
        });
    });

    describe('Login', () => {
        let page: LoginPage;
        let baseUrl: string;

        beforeEach(() => {
            page = new LoginPage();
            page.navigateTo('/login');
            baseUrl = page.baseUrl;
        });

        it('check the login page title', async () => {
            expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('DCMon Dashboard | Login');
        });

        it('login with wrong user', async () => {
            let user = 'baduser@test.com';
            let password = '123456';
            expect(page.getText('.m-login__title')).toEqual('Sign In To Admin');
            expect(page.setUser(user)).toEqual(user);
            expect(page.setPassword(password)).toEqual(password);
            page.submit();
            expect(page.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(baseUrl + 'login');
        });

        it('login with correct user', async () => {
            let user = 'test@test.com';
            let password = '123456';
            expect(page.getText('.m-login__title')).toEqual('Sign In To Admin');
            expect(page.setUser(user)).toEqual(user);
            expect(page.setPassword(password)).toEqual(password);
            page.submit();
            expect(page.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(baseUrl + '');
        });
    });

    describe('Add Modbus Device', async () => {
        let page: AppPage;
        let baseUrl: string;

        beforeEach(() => {
            page = new AppPage();
            page.navigateTo('/add-modbus-device');
            baseUrl = page.baseUrl;
        });

        it('check the login page title', async () => {
            expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('DCMon Dashboard');
        });
    });

    describe('Add Notification-Group', () => {
        let page: AppPage;
        let baseUrl: string;

        beforeEach(() => {
            page = new AppPage();
            page.navigateTo('/notification/groups/add');
            baseUrl = page.baseUrl;
        });

        it('check the page title', async () => {
            expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('DCMon Dashboard');
        });

        it('check the Headers', async () => {
            let text = page.getText('.m-subheader__title');
            expect(text).toEqual('NOTIFICATIONs');
            expect(page.getText('.m-portlet__head-text')).toEqual('Add Group');
        });
    });

});
```

this is my router configuration:

```
[
{
        path: "",
        component: ThemeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: DefaultComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "modbus-devices",
                        component: DeviceListComponent,
                        data: { deviceType: 'modbus' }
                    },
                    {
                        path: "snmp-devices",
                        component: DeviceListComponent,
                        data: { deviceType: 'snmp' }
                    },
                    {
                        path: "add-modbus-device",
                        component: ModbusAddDeviceComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "edit-modbus-device/:id",
                        component: ModbusEditDeviceComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "add-snmp-device",
                        component: SnmpAddDeviceComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "edit-snmp-device/:id",
                        component: SnmpEditDeviceComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "notification/groups",
                        component: NotificationGroupListComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "notification/setting",
                        component: NotificationPrioritySettingComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: "notification/groups/add",
                        component: NotificationGroupAddComponent,
                        data: { edit: false }
                    },
                    {
                        path: "notification/groups/edit/:id",
                        component: NotificationGroupAddComponent,
                        data: { edit: true }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }, {
        path: 'login',
        component: AuthComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'logout',
        component: LogoutComponent
    }
]
```

*updated*:

my authguard code :

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    token: string;

    get authToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    constructor(private _router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        this.token = this.authToken;
        if (this.token) {
            return true;
        }
        if (location.pathname !== '/login') {
            this._router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Tests just passed in login page, in AuthGuard i check if user is logged in (localstorage), user can see the pages or not.
login test is in the first step, user will be logged in, after that the AuthGuard return true when user request to any page.

In every test the requested page will be generated in the browser, but test will fail and return :

```
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 4 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details:[github][1]
```

Comment: Can you share your AuthGuard code?

Comment: update : added my AuthGuard code @Talavera

Comment: Could be because of this `this._router.navigate(['/login']` ? I don't put the / when I call navigate

Comment: show your protractor conf file to see whether  you set any short timeout

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: before using Protractor to log in (get input fields, sendKeys, click login button) you should use `browser.get(['/login'])` (yes, in the protractor code) to make Protractor realise the redirection that just happened through the AuthGuard.
Surprisingly the redirection that happens after logging in is accepted by Protractor without the need for an additional `browser.get`.